# Losing values after Python for loop of JSON

Tags: python, json

Stuck on a simple for loop in python parsing JSON in which some of my records work (return the a value for print), and most do not.  I have confirmed that the JSON record does have data within the 'description' node.  I think somehow the values are overwritten.

Here is the loop:

```
        features = json_record['features']
        title_list = []
        description_list = []
        for i in features:
            title = i['title']
            title_list.append(title)
            description = i['description']
            description_list.append(description)
            print description_list  # this ALWAYS works, and returns the list
        print description_list  # this only SOMETIMES work, else returns nothing
```

Sample json:

`"features":[{"sequence":"0","title":"colors","description":"lighting scenes.","valueOf":"<b>Choose from<\/b><br>favorite lighting scenes."},{"sequence":"1","title":"at your fingertips","description":"light output.","valueOf":"<b>features at your fingertips<\/b><br>light output."}`

Comment: Can you share an input/output pair that exemplifies the issue?

Comment: @Sebastian added json

Comment: So, this code is called multiple times and sometimes it prints... what? Literally nothing or perhaps `[]`? You'd get an empty list if the `"features"` list is empty. To debug, add `assert features, "need features"` right before the `for` loop to see if your assumptions are correct.

Comment: I guess, it would be easier to help you if you could explain what are you going to achieve... And as @tdelaney has said, the description_list most probably gets empty after the loop. Are you sure that this particular piece of code is working as you've described?

Comment: In addition to the json, can you add what exactly is being printed? Is this the exact piece of code you're running, or did you extract it from a larger program and are only showing the "relevant" part?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but it still not clear what is the goal.

```
json_record = {
    "features":
        [{"sequence":"0", "title":"colors", "description":"lighting scenes.","valueOf":"<b>Choose from<\/b><br>favorite lighting scenes."},
         {"sequence":"1","title":"at your fingertips","description":"light output.","valueOf":"<b>features at your fingertips<\/b><br>light output."}
        ]
}

title_list = []
description_list = []

[(description_list.append(f["description"]),  title_list.append(f["title"]))
 for f in json_record["features"]
]
print title_list
print description_list
```

Comment: This shrinks the code but doesn't produce `title_list` and doesnt fix a problem. OP will still see the odd results.